# Extracting Distance from FacetWP Proximity Function to Display in Wordpress Template

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, array, directory, geo-data

I am quite new to Wordpress & Php coding in general, I have a relatively simple theme that I have been working with that contains a custom post type that stores latitude and longitude. Each post is a listing a hotel listing within a directory. The theme I am using also integrates with FacetWP the faceting plugin for WordPress. It is possible for the user to search the site by typing a location of locating themselves, this happens using Googles Mapping functionality. When the search is submitted parameters are passed to an archive page:

http://localhost:8888/wowgoddess/listings/?fwp_location=43.653226%2C-79.38318429999998%2C10%2CToronto%252C%2520ON%252C%2520Canada&fwp_sort=distance

decoded this comes out as:

43.653226,-79.38318429999998,10,Toronto%2C%20ON%2C%20Canada

So form passes the archive the central latitude and longitude as well at the radius (10 miles).

The archive then uses this information to query the post type listings to return nearby locations.

What I really want to do is display the distance of each post from the central location in the archive / post overview page.

This should be possible as the theme has a sort by distance sort option. I just can't work out how to grab the calculated value and echo it in the page body. the php for the proximity function is:

```
<?php

if ( class_exists( 'FacetWP_Facet_Proximity' ) ) {
return;
}

class FacetWP_Facet_Proximity
{

/**
* The ordered array of post IDs
*/
public $ordered_posts = array();


/**
* An array containing each post ID and its distance
*/
public $distance = array();


function __construct() {
$this->label = __( 'Proximity', 'fwp' );

add_filter( 'facetwp_index_row', array( $this, 'index_latlng' ), 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'facetwp_sort_options', array( $this, 'sort_options' ), 1, 2     );
add_filter( 'facetwp_filtered_post_ids', array( $this, 'sort_by_distance' ), 10, 2 );
}


/**
 * Generate the facet HTML
*/
function render( $params ) {

$output = '';
$facet = $params['facet'];
$value = $params['selected_values'];
$unit = empty( $facet['unit'] ) ? 'mi' : $facet['unit'];

$lat = empty( $value[0] ) ? '' : $value[0];
$lng = empty( $value[1] ) ? '' : $value[1];
$chosen_radius = empty( $value[2] ) ? '' : $value[2];
$location_name = empty( $value[3] ) ? '' : urldecode( $value[3] );

$radius_options = apply_filters( 'facetwp_proximity_radius_options', array( 10, 25, 50, 100, 250 ) );

ob_start(); ?>
<input type="text" id="facetwp-location" value="<?php echo $location_name;     ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter location', 'fwp' ); ?>" />

<select id="facetwp-radius">
    <?php foreach ( $radius_options as $radius ) : ?>
    <?php $selected = ( $chosen_radius == $radius ) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $radius; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo "$radius $unit"; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<div style="display:none">
    <input type="text" class="facetwp-lat" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>" />
    <input type="text" class="facetwp-lng" value="<?php echo $lng; ?>" />
</div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}


/**
 * Filter the query based on selected values
 */
function filter_posts( $params ) {
global $wpdb;

$facet = $params['facet'];
$selected_values = $params['selected_values'];
$unit = empty( $facet['unit'] ) ? 'mi' : $facet['unit'];
$earth_radius = ( 'mi' == $unit ) ? 3959 : 6371;

if ( empty( $selected_values ) || empty( $selected_values[0] ) ) {
    return 'continue';
}

$lat = (float) $selected_values[0];
$lng = (float) $selected_values[1];
$radius = (int) $selected_values[2];

$sql = "
SELECT DISTINCT post_id,
( $earth_radius * acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( facet_value ) ) * cos( radians( facet_display_value ) - radians( $lng ) ) + sin( radians( $lat ) ) * sin( radians( facet_value ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}facetwp_index
WHERE facet_name = '{$facet['name']}'
HAVING distance < $radius
ORDER BY distance";

$this->ordered_posts = array();
$this->distance = array();

if ( apply_filters( 'facetwp_proximity_store_distance', false ) ) {
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    foreach ( $results as $row ) {
        $this->ordered_posts[] = $row->post_id;
        $this->distance[ $row->post_id ] = $row->distance;
    }
}
else {
    $this->ordered_posts = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
}

return $this->ordered_posts;
}
```

Any assistance you can offer would be appreciated, I have tried reading up on wpquery and experimenting with that i.e. within the post loop using:

```
global $wp_query, $post;
$distance = $wp_query->locations[$post->ID];
```

but that does not seem to return anything according to var dump, I am using the Listify theme and the developers of that - Astoundify do not offer much support.  This seems too small a requirement to brief a developer for so hoping somebody will help me.  Happy to make a small paypal donation if that helps?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: This is a question you should probably ask via FacetWP support, 3rd-party plugins and themes are off-topic here.

Comment: Hi Milo many thanks for the feedback, I think this proximity integration with the theme is via Astoundify from a theme integration perspective... I tried them an they provide limited help.  I am sure it should be easy to get this as the value is being used to enable "order by" I just want to echo the value the order logic is using, but I am unsure how to hook into it :-(  Do you know anybody that take mini tasks like this if I get no success with the FacetWP guys?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial for this exact functionality: https://facetwp.com/proximity-facet-show-post-distance/

The proximity facet is now built into FacetWP core. This tutorial requires at least FacetWP 2.2.7 and Listify 1.0.7. Please upgrade if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi Matt, that worked perfectly.  I should have managed to find that solution, I think I thought the answer would have to come via some custom php.  I will let the Listify guys know about this and update this questions in other places I have asked it.  **Thanks so much for your help!**